# Isolate polymer custom elements for use in others custom elements

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

**Is it possible to ensure certain custom elements are available only within particular custom element?**

For example, I've created a `site-heading` and a `help-icon` element.

```
<polymer-element name="site-heading">
    <template>
        <h1>
            <content></content>
            <content select="help-icon"></content>
        </h1>
    </template>
<polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="help-icon">
    <template>
        <span class="help">
            <img src="/image/help.png" />
            <content></content>
        </span>
    </template>
<polymer-element>
```

Now this isn't the most practical example, however, let's say the `help-icon` is a highly specialized element that only has meaning in context to `site-heading`. **How can I force the element to be used only inside of `site-heading`?**

#### Yay!

```
<site-heading>
    Super Cool Site Header
    <help-icon>Help Me!</help-icon>
</site-heading>
```

#### Nay!

```
<help-icon>Help Me!</help-icon>
```

---

**Update 2: @ebidel**

It seems this relationship isn't really supported and may not even be in the specs. Here is a real world cases I believe should weight heavy in consideration of scoped (isolated?) elements.

Let's assume a vendor would create a shippable web component. For example, SoundCloud would create a `<soundcloud-player>` element. A player needs a track list, so they create a `<track-info attributes="track-id crop etc">{{HTML for description pane}}</track-info>` element.

The `<track-info>` element is only useful as a child of `<soundcloud-player>`:

- Currently, in theory `<track-info>` is completely fine, until a new web component defines a `<track-info>` element.
- Does is really make sense that every element a vendor might create be prefixed with their name? ie. `<soundcloud-track-info>`

*Should we move this conversation somewhere else as it appears we already have the answer to my original question?*

Answer (score 1):

The HTML parser only reserves a few tags to behave like this (they're ignored if they're not under a certain parent):

- `<option>`/`<optgroup>` can only be used as a child of `<select>`.
- `<tr>` can only be child of `<table>`
- [others](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/blob/master/src/TemplateBinding.js#L141%3aL153)

My first question is whether it `help-icon` needs to be a component. Composition is a good thing :) If it's useful to you now, it may be useful in other places.

To get this working...I would do what you have done in `site-header`. Only select `<help-icon>` using `<content select="help-icon"></content>`. Second, you can test for what parent the element is a child of in `domReady()`:

```
<polymer-element name="help-icon" hidden>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('help-icon', {
      domReady: function() {
        // help-icon should only be a parent of site-banner.
        // Unhide
        if (this.parentNode.localName == 'site-banner') {
          this.hidden = false;
        } else {
          //this.remove(); // optionally remove it from the dom.
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dazewiqa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. I've added more info to my question.